# Having trouble installing Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

So this is my first time asking a question here, so please bear with me. For the past few DAYS I've been trying to install rspec onto my system. After an introductory project a couple of months ago I became familiar with the fact that my Mac has ruby installed and it won't let me really install any gems as it would reply with a permissions denied notice. So I installed ruby from homebrew and went about my coding. Now present day I want to install rspec following a walkthrough I'm working on but the system won't let me. I've looked online and I thought it was my PATH and even tried changing it multiple times and it wouldn't work. At one point my terminal wouldn't even read the entirety of my `bash_profile` even though I `source`'d the file more than once. I've since updated to `zsh` and it's the exact same thing.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt:${PATH}"
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/sbin"

PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin:${PATH}" export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

echo "Hello World"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Have you tried rbenv or rvm? it can make working with gem(sets) easier, setting up paths and so on.

Comment: used `gem install bundler rspec` still doesn't work unfortunately